# How to resolve KeyStoreConnectException on Android 10?

Tags: android, android-keystore, android-security, keystore-access

My app is working pretty well on all the Android OS except Android 10. I am using the Motorola One Power device which got updated with Android 10. We are using Android Keystore to encrypt databases.

App is getting crash on luanch with below error.

> android.security.keystore.KeyStoreConnectException: Failed to communicate with keystore service
>           at android.security.keystore.AndroidKeyStoreCipherSpiBase.ensureKeystoreOperationInitialized(AndroidKeyStoreCipherSpiBase.java:256)
>           at android.security.keystore.AndroidKeyStoreCipherSpiBase.engineInit(AndroidKeyStoreCipherSpiBase.java:148)
>           at javax.crypto.Cipher.tryTransformWithProvider(Cipher.java:2980)

Its a KeyStoreConnectException issue. The app is taking time to connect to KeyStoreConnectException.

**Note: If I run the app in debugged mode then it's working fine.**

Please help me to find solution. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I have the same issue and I realized that it only happens when using the cipher on a background thread. If I do it on the main thread it works just fine.
Did you found any solution to this?

Comment: I use it on the main thread and still get this error in Crashlytics

Comment: Did you manage to resolve this bug?

Answer (score 4):

As MatPag pointed out, this is a [known bug](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/147384380) in Android 10 that's not present in earlier or later versions. As I call Cipher::init() in several places, here is a convenient wrapper function in Kotlin:

```
private fun keyStoreWorkaroundForAndroid10(f: () -> Unit) {
    for (i in 0..3) {
        try {
            f()
            return
        } catch (e: ProviderException) {
            Timber.d("Applying Android 10 KeyStoreConnectException bug workaround. Counter: ${i}, Exception: ${e.message}")
            Thread.sleep(100)
            continue
        }
    }
}
```

And then you call it like this (remember - in a background thread):

```
keyStoreWorkaroundForAndroid10 {
    cipherEncrypt.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, publicKey)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a known bug tracked here https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/147384380

Google fixed it and probably will be available in Android 11.

We currently don't know if it will be fixed with security patches on Android 10 at some point

Comment: still have this bug in android 12 and android 13

Answer (score -1):

I think your code run takes long time, you can move to the thread, try it!